# Scatter plot for non numeric data

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe

I am learning to use matplotlib with pandas and I am having a little trouble with it. There is a dataframe which has districts and coffee shops as its y and x labels respectively. And the column values represent the start date of the coffee-shops in respective districts

```
          starbucks    cafe-cool      barista   ........    60 shops
dist1     2008-09-18  2010-05-04     2007-02-21   ...............
dist2     2007-06-12  2011-02-17       
dist3
.
.
100 districts
```

I want to plot a scatter plot with x axis as time series and y axis as coffee-shops. Since I couldn't figure out a direct one line way to plot this, I extracted the coffee-shops as one list and dates as other list.

```
shops = list(df.columns.values)
dt = pd.DataFrame(df.ix['dist1'])
dates = dt.set_index('dist1')
```

First I tried `plt.plot(dates, shops)`. Got a ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero - error. I could not figure out the reason for it. I saw on some posts that the data should be numeric, so I used ytick function.

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...60]
```

still `plt.plot(dates, y)` threw same ZeroDivisionError. If I could get past this may be I would be able to plot using tick function. Source -
 http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html

I am trying to plot the graph for only first row/dist1. For that I fetched the first row as a dataframe  `df1 = df.ix[1]` and then used the following

```
for badges, dates in df.iteritems():

    date = dates

    ax.plot_date(date, yval)

    # Record the number and label of the coffee shop
    label_ticks.append(yval)
    label_list.append(badges)
    yval+=1
```

. 
I got an error at line `ax.plot_date(date, yval)` saying x and y should be have same first dimension. Since I am plotting one by one for each coffe-shop for dist1 shouldn't the length always be one for both x and y? PS: date is a datetime.date object

Comment: Are the dates "2008-09-18" being passed as datetime objects or strings? It seems to me that you should iterate through each coffee shop, can you give a minimum working example for just one coffee shop?

Comment: You could have the x axis as dates and the y axis as districts, then use a third variable (represented by different colours) to outline your 60 different shops.

Comment: @Greg : The dates are being passed as string objects. What do you mean by working example for one coffee shop?

Comment: Once you get your dates figured out there is also a nice way to map categories to numeric values using dicts in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041905/matplotlib-timelines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to convert the dates to datetimes, see [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html) for
an example. As mentioned you also need to convert the coffee shops into 
some numbering system then change the tick labels accordingly.

Here is an attempt

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def get_datetime(string):
    "Converts string '2008-05-04' to datetime"
    return datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d")

# Generate datarame
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
             starbucks=["2008-09-18", "2007-06-12"],
             cafe_cool=["2010-05-04", "2011-02-17"],
             barista=["2007-02-21"]),
             index=["dist1", "dist2"])

ax = plt.subplot(111)

label_list = []
label_ticks = []
yval = 1 # numbering system

# Iterate through coffee shops
for coffee_shop, dates in df.iteritems():

    # Convert strings into datetime list
    datetimes = [get_datetime(date) for date in dates] 

    # Create list of yvals [yval, yval, ...] to plot against
    yval_list = np.zeros(len(dates))+yval

    ax.plot_date(datetimes, yval_list)

    # Record the number and label of the coffee shop
    label_ticks.append(yval)
    label_list.append(coffee_shop)

    yval+=1 # Change the number so they don't all sit at the same y position

# Now set the yticks appropriately
ax.set_yticks(label_ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(label_list)

# Set the limits so we can see everything
ax.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim()[0]-1,
            ax.get_ylim()[1]+1)
```

Comment: This solves my problem. Still I didn't understand why did I get the zerodivisionerror?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with what you have given. Post a working example that gives the error and that may be easier to diagnose.