# When using mpld3.fig_to_html(fig), I cannot seem to use plugins, and the panning/zoom behaviour is different

Tags: python, mpld3

I want to create a plot with the zoom properties of [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/aflaxman/8780140), with tooltips like [this](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/html_tooltips.html), and no spines like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32626852/432913).

There are a few problems, first, when I do a standard plot with no plugins, I get the same home/pan/zoom buttons as in the second plot - not as in the first, which I want.

Then, the spines still show up, despite having disabled them.

and third, I do not have the `ConfigurableZoomAndPan` plugin as in the third example.

Do I have to download the plugins separately? I have the latest version of mpld3.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question though one of the notebooks you shared is useful to me. Does the code in http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/aflaxman/8780140 for work you? In my case it complains about plugins saying: " 'module' object has no attribute 'ResetButton' "
Also I can do `mpld3.enable_notebook()` but doing `mpld3.enable_notebook("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.1/d3.min.js")` leads to errors.

Comment: i didn't try it since i don't have the pluggins (and so would get that same error)

Comment: do you know where I can get the plugins? :)
Also, I just asked a question related to mpld3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085978/ipython-notebook-horizontal-zoom?noredirect=1#comment59816497_36085978

Comment: You do not have to download plugins separately, but it sounds like you will benefit from having [the latest code from github](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3).  Can you share what you have tried so far? A small example of where you are stuck can be very helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AbrahamDFlaxman thanks. I'll check this out when i get some time.