# Ipython notebook horizontal zoom

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, mpld3

I have subplots in an ipython notebook. I can zoom in inline using the `mpld3` module. However, right now I can only zoom into a rectangle. Due to my application's nature I need horizontal zoom.

Is there a way to zoom horizontally (using your cursor) in matplotlib? Better yet can I set the zoom to be horizontal via code without any keyboard manipulation? In Matlab, I can do this by setting:

`figure(1); h=zoom; set(h,'Motion','horizontal','Enable','on');`

Here is a minimal example in python:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3
import numpy as np
mpld3.enable_notebook()
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.cos(x)

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(x,z)
```

Comment: If you can zoom with a rectangle, can't you just set it's height to match the vertical limits of your plot?

Comment: @Dan, you mean with my cursor? That is pretty difficult and you can easily mess up. Horizontal zoom makes sense if you have a time series.

Comment: I assumed you meant rectangular zoom via code

Comment: @Dan, no I want to use my mouse for zooming into different segments of my time series. So I will be using my cursor for investigating the signal but I would like to do it horizontally instead of rectangularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/), which is great to create interactive plots in Jupyter.

You can get more info on how to plot time series with it [HERE](https://plot.ly/python/time-series/) and info on subplots [HERE](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/). Here is what I made with your data, hopefully it does what you want!

```
%matplotlib inline
import plotly
from plotly import tools
import numpy as np
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode() # run at the start of every notebook

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.cos(x)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y)
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=z)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Hi Cynthia, looks great. The only thing missing is linking the axes but I guess that can be done. Quick question though: I am doing a PhD on statistical inference for time series models and I used Matlab till now. I am painfully trying to complete my transition from matlab to python. What are your thoughts on matplotlib/mpld3 vs plotly? Is one preferable to another (especially in the context of AI and ML)?

Comment: Hello @YBE, I'm actually fairly new to Plotly myself, so I can't really tell yet,  but it seems like a great tool when using Jupyter notebooks. I do think that people have a lot more experience with matplotlib, making it a well documented/explored tool. So far, I see Plotly as a fancier method, geared for special needs, but maybe I will change my mind when I get more used to it...!