# Plot a boolean timeline as horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to visually represent the status of devices (being either offline or online) as a timeline. My data (for one device) looks like this, where True represents online and False represents offline:

```
Time
2019-09-01 14:38:38     True
2019-09-01 14:39:08     True
2019-09-01 14:39:38     True
2019-09-01 14:40:08     True
2019-09-01 14:40:38     True

2019-10-04 17:35:55     True
2019-10-04 17:36:25    False
2019-10-04 17:36:55    False
2019-10-04 17:37:25    False
2019-10-04 17:37:55     True
Name: Time, Length: 95368, dtype: bool
```

I would like to represent this as a horizontal barchart where datetime is on the x-axis and each device has its own bar with green representing online and red for offline.

What I'm trying to do is similar to what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951911/plot-a-binary-timeline-in-matplotlib). I copied that code and adapted it slightly:

```
# plot green for event==1
s1 = data[data == 1].astype(int)
inxval = matplotlib.dates.date2num(s1.index.to_pydatetime())
times= list(zip(inxval, np.ones(len(s1))))
plt.broken_barh(times, (-1,1), color="green")

# plot red for event==0
s2 = data[data == 0].astype(int)
inxval = matplotlib.dates.date2num(s2.index.to_pydatetime())
times= list(zip(inxval, np.ones(len(s2))))
plt.broken_barh(times, (-1,1), color="red")

#format axes
ax.margins(0)
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.dates.DayLocator())
monthFmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%b")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthFmt)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately this takes forever to load (my dataset is quite large) and I'd like to directly have the timestamps as the x-axis, so without using date2num. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The code seems correct. One cannot find out what "forever to load" means and what you would like to be more elegantly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, the code is correct in the sense that it works. However, it takes about 15 seconds to load with 95k datapoints whereas a simple line chart of the same data loads almost instantly. Additionally, I'd like to have nicer x-labels that are generated automatically based on the timestamps, just like plt.plot(data). The linked question is from 2017 so perhaps there are more efficient ways of solving this problem now.

Comment: 15 seconds is not too surprising for 100k of datapoints. Mind that bars are different from lines. But of course you could create a `LineCollection` instead, to make it faster. The labels are the result of a locator/formatter. You can hence use the same locator/formatter you get with `plt.plot`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Okay, and how would one go about creating a line collection and using the same locator/formatter as plt.plot?