# Timeline in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, timeline, plotnine

Is there any way to create a timeline in Python similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492274/draw-a-chronological-timeline-with-ggplot2) using only 1 vizualiation package and no other setup? I have tried to use the `plotnine` package to use ggplot2 within Python but this is quite cumbersome to get it to work. Furthermore, I have tried the [`labella`](https://github.com/GjjvdBurg/labella.py) package but this requires installation of a Latex distribution. With `matplotlib` I can't find a way to include the comments next to the event bars.

Comment: You could also try [link](http://pyqtgraph.org/), however it is definately possible with matplotlib. Maybe you should ask a question about including the comments in matplotlib? Yes-No questions dont work that well on stackoverflow.

Comment: This question is really broad because there is no timeline command in matplotlib. You can have a look at the [text examples of the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) or try to adapt [examples that annotate bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots). When you have a specific question, you should ask this one.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue ... and this is my solution. Please ignore the Ugly Color Generation ... this is more of a work in progress.

It is Python 3.6 tested ....

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
from cycler import cycler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

idx = pd.date_range('2018-1-1', '2018-9-10', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Offset': 20,'val': 2}, index=idx)
df['Offset']=[n for n in range(0,len(df))]

sched=[{'name':'tim',
     'jobs':{
          1:(datetime(2018,1,1,),datetime(2018,2,1)),
          2:(datetime(2018,4,1) ,datetime(2018,5,1)),
          3:(datetime(2018,6,1) ,datetime(2018,7,1))}
       },
       {'name':'BiMonthly',
     'jobs':{
          1:(datetime(2018,2,1,),datetime(2018,3,1)),
          2:(datetime(2018,5,1) ,datetime(2018,6,1)),
          3:(datetime(2018,7,1) ,datetime(2018,8,1))}
       }
       ,
          {'name':'Monthly',
     'jobs':{
           1:(datetime(2018,2,1),datetime(2018,2,10)),
           2:(datetime(2018,3,1),datetime(2018,3,10)),
           3:(datetime(2018,4,1),datetime(2018,4,10)),
           4:(datetime(2018,5,1),datetime(2018,5,10)),
           5:(datetime(2018,6,1),datetime(2018,6,10))
         }},
        {'name':'LongTerm',
     'jobs':{
           1:(datetime(2018,2,1),datetime(2018,5,1))
         }
        }]

color_cycle = cycler(c=['r', 'g', 'b'])
ls_cycle = cycler('ls', ['-', '--'])
sty_cycle = ls_cycle * ( color_cycle)

def get_offset(when):
    global df
    if type(when)==str:
        when=pd.to_datetime(when)
    try:
        return df.loc[when]['Offset']
    except KeyError:
        print("{} Not Found".format(when))
        return -1

thickness=0.3
timelines=[]

start_period = idx[0].to_period('D').ordinal

for a_job_group in sched:
    timeline=[]
    print("-----")
    for keys in a_job_group['jobs']:
        #print("Dates {} {}".format(a_job_group['jobs'][keys][0],
        #                     a_job_group['jobs'][keys][1]))

        offset_start = get_offset(a_job_group['jobs'][keys][0])
        offset_end   = get_offset(a_job_group['jobs'][keys][1])
        print("offset {} {} TimeSpan {}".format(offset_start, 
                                                offset_end, offset_end - offset_start))  
        timeline_data=(start_period + offset_start,offset_end-offset_start)
        timeline.append(timeline_data)
    timelines.append(timeline)

pos= 0
df.drop(['Offset'],axis=1,inplace=True,)
ax = df.plot(color='w')
col_schema=[s for s in sty_cycle]
for t in timelines:
    ax.broken_barh(t, [pos, thickness],
                   color=col_schema[pos]['c'],
                  linestyle=col_schema[pos]['ls'])
    pos+= 1
plt.show()
```

What does it output ?

[image]

I have to add an Index - and to check that I can change the TimeSteps (hours weeks etc) but so far this it the best solution I can find.

I plan to add **mpld3** to it - and then to run it via Flask.... So I have a little ways to go.